# use of "this" and "class" as members

Tags: java

I have seen Java code that says something like:

```
SomeClass.this.someMethod(someArg);
Blah(AnotherClass.class);
Blah(YAClass.this);
```

What do "this" and "class" mean here?  I am used to them as keywords to refer to the current object and to define a class, but this is different.  My Java book and online searches have not yielded any explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SomeClass.this`/`YAClass.this` - the `this` reference of an inner class' enclosing `SomeClass`/`YAClass` class.

```
class SomeClass {
    private InnerClass {
        public void foo() {
            SomeClass outerThis = SomeClass.this;
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

(You need to be very careful which `this` you get particularly when dealing with operations that could be applied to any `Object` reference. A common case is syncronising on `this` in an inner class, when the code should be synchronising on the outer instance (a better approach in this case is to use an explicit lock object).)

`AnotherClass.class` - the `java.lang.Class` object for the `AnotherClass` class. Prior to Java 1.5 this was implemented using `Class.forName` (initialising the class); from 1.5 the `ldc` bytecode has been extended for direct support.

```
Class<AnotherClass> clazz = AnotherClass.class;
```

Both were introduced in Java 1.1.

Answer (score 3):

A quick example for inner class, to complete the other answers:

```
class SomeClass {
     public void someMethod() {
          System.out.println("Hello, I have someMethod");
     }
     public void otherMethod() {
          addListener(new MyListener() {
              public void someMethod () {
                  System.out.println("I too, have someMethod");
              }
              public void listen() {
                   // I will call someMethod of SomeClass:
                   SomeClass.this.someMethod();
              }
          });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.class` refers to the `Class` object corresponding to your instance's class.  Java keeps one `Class` around in memory per referenced type.

Here is the Javadoc for `Class`: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

The only time I have seen `SomeClass.this` used is when you are dealing with nested classes, and need to refer to the instance of the outer class from the inner class.  See here for an example:  http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2009/04/07/java-nested-inner-class-this/

Answer (score 1):

The `.class` syntax refers to a particular instance of the [Class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class.

The `.this` syntax is usually used from within inner classes to refer to the enclosing instance of the top-level class.  If you used just `this` from within an inner class it would refer to the instance of the inner class and not the enclosing class.